# How to remove app name from Expo Push Notification?

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, expo

Is there any way to remove my app name from the title of a push notification?

I'm using Expo Push Notification services, but it seems it will always include it at the beggining of the title.

Here's a screenshot, you can see that in my app, the name is included, but for example in Gmail's (or any other) it isn't.

[image]

(Just to make it clear, I want the app title, in this case, to be "Morning Brew". But it's automatically adding the app name)

Thanks!

**PS: I haven't tested if it still shows up when building the standalone app. Will do it today and update the question**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively, the name dissapears when you build the standalone app, it only shows up when you're debugging with the Expo app.